# Pointing A Domain To A NameServer

Tags: dns, hosting

Ok I have Hosted a domain on A Company "MadeInHosting.com" I have waited 72 Hour And then visited The Site And It Said To Me "We Could Not Find This Webpage" The site should be in here [AndroidArabia.com.lb](http://androidarabia.com.lb) When I Switch To The Domain in the cpanel it report me this error:

```
Your domain is not pointing to our nameservers at the moment, so services such as FTP,    
File Manager, Website Builder, E-mail (and others) will not work correctly. You can find 
our nameservers at the "Accounts -> Details" section. Please mind that DNS might take up 
to 24 hours to propagate when the change is submitted.
```

I Have Found the DNS Zone Editor with the following records:

```
+--------------------+-----+---------------------+
|androidarabia.com.lb|A    |31.170.166.64        |
+--------------------+-----+---------------------+
|ftp                 |A    |31.170.166.64        |
+--------------------+-----+---------------------+
|www                 |CNAME|androidarabia.com.lb |
+--------------------+-----+---------------------+
|androidarabia.com.lb|MX   |mx1.madeinhosting.com|
+--------------------+-----+---------------------+
|androidarabia.com.lb|NS   |ns4.main-hosting.com |
+--------------------+-----+---------------------+
|androidarabia.com.lb|NS   |ns3.main-hosting.com |
+--------------------+-----+---------------------+
|androidarabia.com.lb|NS   |ns2.main-hosting.com |
+--------------------+-----+---------------------+
|androidarabia.com.lb|NS   |ns1.main-hosting.com |
+--------------------+-----+---------------------+
```

I have full Control on that table And Those are information in the Details:

```
                       Name Servers Details

     ns1.main-hosting.com               31.170.163.241

     ns1.main-hosting.com               64.191.115.234

     ns1.main-hosting.com               173.192.183.247

     ns1.main-hosting.com               31.170.164.249

You can also point your domain ("A" DNS record) to this IP: 31.170.166.64
```

The Question Is How To Point My Domain To Their NameServers so I can fix this error.
P.S.:Those Settings Are Default

Comment: Is ns1.main-hosting.com the correct NameServer for the hosting package? Most companies don't provide DNS hosting for free, you need to purchase the package and then they will update their Name Servers to include your domain (and advise you the Name Servers to put in your NS records).

Comment: @Fizz I don't Know I have Purchased the package and it is like this I do not know how to edit anything P.S.:I have tried The Website Preview and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no domain registered named "**androidarabia.com.lb**".

`nslookup androidarabia.com.lb` returns

```
*** UnKnown can't find androidarabia.com.lb: Non-existent domain
```

and Registry search at http://www.aub.edu.lb/lbdr/Pages/index.aspx says "no matching entries".

It seems that the company where you purchased the domain, actually did not register it for you. (Registration process is as follows - Company where you purchase the domain should contact .com.lb registry (which is probably Lebanese government-subordinate organisation) and register the domain for you.) Either your hosting company did not do that or .com.lb registry is slow to process their request.

Only when your domain is officially registered, it may start to work. Verify at the above URL or with nslookup.

Comment: 10X you that it .com.lb has a big Delay Time Thank You all For Your Time